# How can I add <release note> node in nuget package release?

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package, nuget-server

I have just started learning about TFS and Nuget packages. So every time I release the new nuget package. I could see the version, Author, Date, publish, Tags and Descriptions (See image 1 below). **Now, I want to add a field called Release Notes.** For this, I did modifications in metadata file and was successfully able to add the node in metadata. But whenever I try to install new package through TFS, I want to see or read the details of the package same as version, author. But issue here is I can not see that field in tfs in spite of me modifying it in metadata (please see image 2):

[image: image how it looks after adding node]

Can someone please help me to figure out how can I reflect this  field in the TFS each time, I install new nuget package or update new Nuget package? End goal here is I want to read the details of the package through the releases note field, what it has inside and then only take it if I need it or else Skip it.

Comment: its does let me add more than one pic, so i could not include image1

Comment: Your screenshots are of Visual Studio... What does this have to do with TFS?

Comment: How did you install new package through TFS ? What's the result if you directly install nuget-package locally in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and you may need to wait for Nuget 3.6 version to get it work. Refer to following links for details:

[Feature Request: Add Gallery link & Release notes](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1823)

[Update NuGet to 3.6 to bring back release notes](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/2834)